# Square Uv map: fill the Uv layout

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

This is my Uv map

[image]

My target is to max and optimize my Uv, in particular I would like it matches the whole Uv space. One solution could be scale the whole Uv from x axis and move all until the match will be perfect but, I should watch that corners and slides will match perfectly with the gray square in the background (it looks a "more or less" method).

I'm not sure this would be the best way to achieve the the best result.

**My question is:
Is there a way to spread the UV all long the UV space, keeping its topology? Any advice? Or, is there a method to fill the gap of the uv space? Can a feature of Blender achieve this?**

***EDIT
My Uv map was created with an unwrap***

Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course it depends on what your model looks like and the image texture itself, but the real question is: Does it make sense? Maxing out UV space is quite nice but in the end you really want to avoid stretching.

Comment: It makes sense because i'm using a seamless texture and i need that my uv map cover the entire uv layout in order to avoid seams. The stretch should be uniform long all the x axis

Comment: That's the "old" way of texturing, thus it makes not much sense to me. The new way would be "painting away the seams". And again - depending on what your seamless texture looks like, uniform stretching along the x axis would still result in non-uniform stretching along the y axis.

Comment: That's interesting! Can you link me a tutorial or materials, dealing with this new technique? This could save my life ^^

Comment: Here's one, but the sound is really awful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHyNEC1739c . 3 Minutes into the video he starts with texture painting using the clone brush.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46425/discussion-between-fuboski-and-metaphor-set).

Comment: In UVImageEditor press E.

Comment: Scale along x using the cursor as pivot (period button), assuming that the cursor remains where it is now (at the leftmost edge).

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully your 2D cursor is at the bottom left of your UV layout image area - if not, position it there.

In toolbar area, choose "2D Cursor" as Rotation/Scaling Pivot.

In the UVs menu --> select "Constrain to Image Bounds"

Now select all of the vertices in your UV.

If the island is not flush with the bottom left: grab (G) and move so the edges are flush with the bottom left (the constraint will ensure that you cannot drag the island past the bounds)

Now, scale (S) - you should be able to scale to the image bounds.

Answer (score 1):

## Right scaling solution

As far as I know there is no tool for fitting the created UV layout to the whole square. But you can do this: 
*[In the UV-Editor]*

1. select all verticies <kbd>A</kbd>
2. scale your vertecies on the x-Axis by the factor 1.45454545. <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + `1.45454545`
3. pack the islands <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (We do this to center the UV-layout. This makes it independent of where your scaling pivot point was)
4. if you want, you can choose a margin, so that your map isn't exactly in the corners (<kbd>F6</kbd>, then enter something like .333 in the margin field)

Your map should be aligned centered now with no space of the light gray square except the margin left.

---

#### Why is the factor 1.45454545?

When you look at the screenshot you can count that 5.5 of 8 (large) squares of the x-Axis grid are filled. So $\frac{5.5} 8 = \frac{11}{16}$. If you want to scale them, so they fit 8 of 8 squares, $\frac 8 8 = \frac 1 1 = 1$, you have to multiply by the inverse, namely $(\frac{11}{16})^{-1} = \frac{16}{11} = 1.\overline{45}$, because $\frac{11}{16}\cdot\frac{16}{11} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Smart UV Project".

- select object
- go to edit mode (tab)
- select all vertices
- press "U" to unwrap
- choose "smart UV project"
- Make sure the checkbox "Stretch the final output to texture bounds" is checked.

Comment: This doesn't "keep its topology" as requested by OP.  This creates a new topology.

Comment: Yep. Anymway, this works only with smart uv project? If I should use the unwrap for more complex mesh? There isn't a similar feature?